# How can I show/hide elements with a specific class on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm fairly new to React and ES6, and I'm trying to develop the functionality so that when a button (.featureBtn) is clicked, a number of elements with a specific class (all .featureBtn elements) are hidden, and another component (Accessories) becomes visible.

Could this be done using state and a ternary statement, and if so how would this be done?

Please see my code below.

```
class ProductView extends React.Component {

  static contextType = ChoicesContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.forwardSequence = this.forwardSequence.bind(this);
    this.reverseSequence = this.reverseSequence.bind(this);
  }

  static sequenceImages(folder, filename, type) {
    let images = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
      images.push(<img src={require(`../images/sequences/${folder}/${filename}_000${i}.jpg`)} alt="" className={`${type} sequenceImage`} />);
    }
    return images;
  }

  async sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
  }

  async forwardSequence(sequence, effect) {
    Array.prototype.reduce.call
      ( sequence
      , (r, img) => r.then(_ => this.sleep(50)).then(_ => effect(img))
      , Promise.resolve()
      )
  }

  async reverseSequence(sequence, effect) {
    Array.prototype.reduceRight.call
      ( sequence
      , (r, img) => r.then(_ => this.sleep(50)).then(_ => effect(img))
      , Promise.resolve()
      )
  }

  render() {
    const etseq = document.getElementsByClassName("exploreTech");
    const uiseq = document.getElementsByClassName("userInterface");

    const { choices } = this.context;
    const CurrentProduct = ProductData.filter(x => x.name === choices.productSelected);

    return (
      <>

        <div className="productInteractive wrapper">
          {CurrentProduct.map((item, i) => (
            <main className={item.slug}>

              <div key={i} className="imageSequence">
                <img src={require(`../images/sequences/${item.static_img}`)} alt="" className="staticImage" />
                {ProductView.sequenceImages(item.explore_tech_img_folder, item.explore_tech_filename, "exploreTech")}
                {ProductView.sequenceImages(item.user_interface_img_folder, item.user_interface_filename, "userInterface")}
              </div>

             {/* When one of the two buttons below are clicked, they should both hide (presumably using the featureBtn class), and the <Accessories /> component should become visible. */}

              <button
                onClick={() => this.forwardSequence(etseq, img => img.style.opacity = 1)}
                className="btn featureBtn userInterfaceBtn"
              >User Interface</button>

              <button
                onClick={() => this.forwardSequence(uiseq, img => img.style.opacity = 1)}
                className="btn-reverse featureBtn exploreTechnologiesBtn"
              >Explore Technologies</button>

           <Accessories />

            </main>
          ))}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default ProductView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it is react, you no need to do with `class` like `vanila js`. You have the access to state, so can call it based on your current state.

```
if(this.state.showFirst) {
  this.showFirst();
} else {
  this.showSecond();
}
```

so this `showFirst and showSecond` can return appropriate elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by adding a state variable .Lets call it show . You can update show to hide when a button is clicked . Use this variable to conditionally change the classnames of the buttons you want to hide.

You can use the [classnames npm package .](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) for adding conditional classnames to the buttons you want to hide .

And use the ternary operator for Accessories. This same state variable can be used to show Accessories or hide it .

```
{ !this.state.show && <Accessories/>}
```

Answer (score 0):

use ternary operator and one state variable, onClick on change state value.

{this.state.stateVariable ? <>Component  : null}

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that first gets the elements to be removed by class name, gets the buttons, and toggles display onClick.

See code

```js
class ProductView extends React.Component {

  static contextType = ChoicesContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.forwardSequence = this.forwardSequence.bind(this);
    this.reverseSequence = this.reverseSequence.bind(this);
  }

  static sequenceImages(folder, filename, type) {
    let images = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
      images.push(<img src={require(`../images/sequences/${folder}/${filename}_000${i}.jpg`)} alt="" className={`${type} sequenceImage`} />);
    }
    return images;
  }

  async sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
  }

  async forwardSequence(sequence, effect) {
    Array.prototype.reduce.call
      ( sequence
      , (r, img) => r.then(_ => this.sleep(50)).then(_ => effect(img))
      , Promise.resolve()
      )
  }

  async reverseSequence(sequence, effect) {
    Array.prototype.reduceRight.call
      ( sequence
      , (r, img) => r.then(_ => this.sleep(50)).then(_ => effect(img))
      , Promise.resolve()
      )
  }
      //function to hide elements with classname .featureBtn. 
  toggleDisplay(){
      const elementsToBeRemoved= document.getElementsByClassName('featureBtn');
      const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); //if it is a specific button, give the button an ID and use getElementById
      if(elementsToBeRemoved){
       elementsToBeRemoved.styles.display('none')
       //insert the other component to be shown 
      } else{
       elementsToBeRemoved.styles.display('inline')
       //hide the other component
      }
      //attach this function on the onClick property and see what happens.

  }
  
  render() {
    const etseq = document.getElementsByClassName("exploreTech");
    const uiseq = document.getElementsByClassName("userInterface");

    const { choices } = this.context;
    const CurrentProduct = ProductData.filter(x => x.name === choices.productSelected);

    return (
      <>

        <div className="productInteractive wrapper">
          {CurrentProduct.map((item, i) => (
            <main className={item.slug}>

              <div key={i} className="imageSequence">
                <img src={require(`../images/sequences/${item.static_img}`)} alt="" className="staticImage" />
                {ProductView.sequenceImages(item.explore_tech_img_folder, item.explore_tech_filename, "exploreTech")}
                {ProductView.sequenceImages(item.user_interface_img_folder, item.user_interface_filename, "userInterface")}
              </div>

             {/* When one of the two buttons below are clicked, they should both hide (presumably using the featureBtn class), and the <Accessories /> component should become visible. */}

              <button
                onClick={() => this.forwardSequence(etseq, img => img.style.opacity = 1)}
                className="btn featureBtn userInterfaceBtn"
              >User Interface</button>

              <button
                onClick={() => this.forwardSequence(uiseq, img => img.style.opacity = 1)}
                className="btn-reverse featureBtn exploreTechnologiesBtn"
              >Explore Technologies</button>

           <Accessories />

            </main>
          ))}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default ProductView;
```